# Obtain attribute type from xpath in Chrome console

Tags: html, xpath

I have been reading xpath cheatsheets such as https://devhints.io/xpath but I'm not finding what I want doing it the way it is suggested.

I'm working on a page with more than 100 blocks like this one:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td>
            <div class="paradaContainer">
                <a class="changue-paraderos" data-id="7" href="https://www.transmilenio.gov.co/loader.php?lServicio=Rutas&amp;lTipo=busqueda&amp;lFuncion=paradas&amp;paradero=7">
                    <span class="fa fa-circle "></span>
                    <span>001A01 - Br. Rincón del Chicó</span>
                </a><br>
                <span class="fa fa-map-marker "></span><span>AC 100 - KR 13</span>
            </div>
            </td></tr>
```

I want to get the URL contained in the **"href"** attribute, so I'm using the following xpath in the Google Chrome console:

```
$x("//tr/td/div/a[@class='changue-paraderos']/@href")
```

The output I wish is:

```
https://www.transmilenio.gov.co/loader.php?lServicio=Rutas&amp;lTipo=busqueda&amp;lFuncion=paradas&amp;paradero=7
```

However, the output obtained is:

```
href
```

So, my question is: How should I get the type of attribute instead of the attribute itself? i.e. How would I get the URL instead of "href"?

It may be a basic question but it has not worked with the documentation I have.

Thanks in advance.

---

I solved this problem. I was indeed receiving output it was nested between a wide range of attributes. Then, I obtained it all first and in a second stage I went for the specific value I wanted:

links_base = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="changue-paraderos"]')

```
for link in links_base:  # Loop para obtener los 200 links por página
    temp = str(link.get_attribute("href"))
    links.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
$x("string(//tr/td/div/a[@class='changue-paraderos']/@href)")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, indeed, it helped me to answer the question. However, I still face two problems: 1) I can only recover one link, how do I make sure of gathering all of them? 2) I need this xpath to webscrapping with Selenium, should I change any of it in order to work? Thanks!

Comment: When I try to use this xpath at Selenium I am receiving this: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression. Do you know why it could be?